# War works fine on local standalone tomcat 7 (no eclipse), does not work when uploaded to ec2

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am able to get the spring blazeds examples and war (http://docs.spring.io/spring-flex/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#pre-built-samples) working locally in tomcat 7 webapps directory (i initially had problems with this but now it works fine locally), however when I upload the same war file to amazon ec2, tomcats starts up fine and i can see the project's index page but none of the projects scripts are executing. According to the catalina.out log, the server started up successfully  without any errors. Please help.

thanks,
tone

***Update**

I am assuming that the problem resides in the blazeds portion of the project? Not sure if it is executing properly. i have enabled ports 8080 and 8400 in the security group.

Comment: share the logs from tomcat.

Comment: I think the big difference between running from eclipse and running in your tomcat is that eclipse resolves the classloader and dependencies among libraries. But, of course, without your tomcat logs as suggested by @sachingarg, we can do nothing to help you

Comment: show tomcat/logs/catalina.out file

Comment: Here is my ec2 link http://ec2-54-80-254-235.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/testdrive/. not sure what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found out the issue. i had to recompile the swf files that comes with the project to point to my ec2 instance url instead of localhost.